# How to retrieve FB comments/shares for a specific URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to retrieve the text,author of comments or shares made for a specific url. 
I have for instance the following target : http://www.graphemeride.com/blog/comment-j-ai-triche-aux-golden-blog-awards

I can retrieve the number of comments and shares [with FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20%0A%20%20%20%20url,%20share_count%20,%20comment_count,%20comments_fbid%0AFROM%20%0A%20%20%20%20link_stat%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%20%20%20%20url=%22http://www.graphemeride.com/blog/comment-j-ai-triche-aux-golden-blog-awards%22) :

```
SELECT 
    url, share_count , comment_count, comments_fbid
FROM 
    link_stat 
WHERE 
    url="http://www.graphemeride.com/blog/comment-j-ai-triche-aux-golden-blog-awards"
```

I get the following result :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "url": "http://www.graphemeride.com/blog/comment-j-ai-triche-aux-golden-blog-awards",
      "share_count": 27,
      "comment_count": 26,
      "comments_fbid": 357167807708699
    }
  ]
}
```

My plan was to use the [comment FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) query to [retrieve the different comments](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20%0A%20%20%20%20id,%20text%0AFROM%20%0A%20%20%20%20comment%0AWHERE%20%0A%20%20%20%20object_id=%22357167807708699%22).

```
SELECT 
    id, text
FROM 
    comment
WHERE 
    object_id="357167807708699"
```

However I get an empty result dataset.
I added the required access token, but kind of understood that I can only get comments I made about this object, not public comments or shares.

Is there an alternative way to get access to what people publicly said about an url ?

Comment: You are using the facebook comment plugin right?

Comment: I don't think it matters. As soon as the count is > 0 it should be able to display the comments.

I would be more interested by the text coming from standard shares, but I think it would be harder to retrieve.

Comment: Well, @SahilMittal, you might have pointed in an interesting direction. I tried with another url where I know there was public comment and got the access to the comment (http://www.suwa.fr/news/terre/vtt/21-riders-corses-516).

However, I don't understand the comment_count if we are not able to retrieve the comments.

Comment: Hmm, I'll get back to you if I found something related

Answer (score 0):

The comment count on the `link_stat` table is the for the number of comments on the SHARES of this link and not the number of comments on the comments plugin on that page itself.

Whereas the `comments` table returns you the number of comments from the comments plugins on that page.

As your page isn't using any fb comments plugin, you don't get any comments back.

Comment: Dear @SahilMittal I am sorry but does not help me to retrieve the text of comments, but only the number of comments.